# Creating bootable USB flash drive with Windows 10 to repair a dual-booting Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows

I plan on clicking "repair laptop" when installing Windows 10. This laptop has Ubuntu dual-booted with Windows 10 already. I get the blue Recovery screen when I boot into Windows.

I want to be really careful, so how do I *ensure* that I will not erase Ubuntu from the computer while clean installing Windows 10?

I read somewhere that every new Windows ISO wipes out everything else on the disk. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been mixed: sometimes (re)installing Windows 10 on a dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows system *sometimes* has proceeded without issue, but on two or three occasions, grub was messed up (which was not a major repair, [though others have had more difficulty repairing grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655011/windows-10-upgrade-kills-grub-and-boot-repair-doesnt-help)), and once, on a newer PC with Intel security, the boot process no longer recognized grub as valid for UEFI, which required going to BIOS/UEFI to reinstall it.

[Other users claim that the Windows installation can actually *delete* (deallocate) an existing Linux partition.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-installer-deletes-linux-partition/10b7dec9-77a2-4f08-a453-2cfb0c23f747)

Therefore, the only secure way to ensure that *at least you're no worse off than when you started* is to **image the entire disk**. Then you can recover the Linux partition after installing Windows. Use any disk backup software, such as free Macrium Reflect, and *verify* that the backup is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I second the idea that you should absolutely back up what you already have, especially because you're not absolutely sure what will happen.

Here's my experience: When you go to reinstall Windows 10 you get two options, **Upgrade** and **Custom**. Every time I've tried the upgrade option it has asked me to boot back into Windows and run it from there instead, so I can't speak much about that, however Custom does give you the flexibility to choose where Windows will be installed with the regular windows partition editor ("Where would you like to install Windows?").  This is the first place you can potentially do some damage.

I usually remove all Windows partitions including any recovery partitions, and if the partitions are contiguous (ie. no non-Windows partitions in between), then deleting these partitions will yield one big "Unallocated Space".  Select that and click Next and Windows will do the rest.  If you accidentally delete the wrong partition on this screen then it's **gone**, and very hard to get back.

Next is the bootloader.  In my experience Windows always overwrites grub, but as DrMoishe Pippik has mentioned, it's usually easy to restore with a live Linux boot disk.

Oh, and did I mention you should back up what you have?